# How can I get the content of an externally loaded script tag?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, cross-domain

I want to have a bookmarklet retrieve data from an external XML file. I thought that I could download it as a script tag (kind of like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/664709/1252748)) and then traverse the `innerHTML` of the script tag using normal DOM methods. but when I get the script

```
fonts = document.createElement("script");
fonts.src = "http://www.myExternal/resource/fonts.xml";
fonts.id = "fontXML";
console.log(fonts.innerHTML) //"" (nothing)
```

I don't get any innerHTML. Is there anyway I can use this strategy (or anything else) to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not allow script content to be browsed like that. So basically you are facing the standard CORS problem.

1. If the external resource can answer with JSONP, then use it in your script tag.
2. If there is proper Allow-Origin header set on the resource, just use AJAX.
3. If it can neither and you have no access to the resource's code to fix it, then the only option I can imagine is to create your own proxy and either set CORS headers or provide JSONP API

Comment: How would JSONP change this situation. I'm not familiar with it at all. Does it help with cross domain?

Comment: @thomas If instead of XML you want the server could return `someCallback({"xml": "<yourData .../>")` then you'll be able to define `someCallback(data) { /*parse data*/ }` so on script automatic execution, your someCallback will be called. Edit: Yes, it does work with any domain.